# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object - how to copy files to an S3 bucket using the code provided in AWS's documentation

Tags: python, boto3

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html

Using the code provided in the documentation, I'm trying to iterate through parent_dir, and if there's a zip file, then I want to copy it to my S3 bucket.

I tried both

```
    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True
```

and

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with open("FILE_NAME", "rb") as f:
    s3.upload_fileobj(f, "BUCKET_NAME", "OBJECT_NAME")
```

but both of them gave the same error.

```
    s3_client = boto3.client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id='MY_KEY_ID',
        aws_secret_access_key='MY_ACCESS_KEY'
    )

    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id='MY_KEY_ID',
        aws_secret_access_key='MY_ACCESS_KEY',
    )

    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('MY_URL')
```

```
    for file in os.listdir(parent_dir):
        if object_name is None:
            object_name = file

        if file.endswith('.zip'):
            with open(file, "rb") as f:
                s3_client.upload_fileobj(f, bucket, object_name)
```

`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: Please add the exception stacktrace (wich will contain the line where it appears), and make sure that line is in the question as well.

Comment: In your last two examples, you are passing a file-handle, not a file-path. The first example seems to follow [this sample](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-s3-upload_file.py.html) exactly, so can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upload3.py", line 180, in <module>
    upload_to_s3()
  File "upload3.py", line 151, in upload_to_s3
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(f, bucket, object_name)```

Comment: Is this good enough? The rest of it contains my personal information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [[AmazonAWS.Boto3]: S3.Client - upload_fileobj(*Fileobj, Bucket, Key, ExtraArgs=None, Callback=None, Config=None*)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj), the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> arguments (*Bucket* and *Key*) must be strings.

But you are passing as a 2<sup>nd</sup> argument:

```py
bucket = s3.Bucket('MY_URL')
```

which is not *OK*. Make it a plain string (and even better, rename it):

```py
bucket_name = "MY_URL"
```

and pass it to *upload_fileobj*, and you should get past this problem.